# Will it ever be possible to add friends?

Tags: feature-request

It would be neat if we could add other users who we like as friends. Or, at least a follow and reciprocal follow option.

In this way cool users we could either make real-life friends or we could simply watch each other's content to see what they put out recently.

Comment: Who would downvote this valid question?

Answer (score 6):

Highly unlikely.

Stack Exchange is explicitly not a social site. The main goal of the network is to create a repository of high-quality questions and answers about many different topics. Puzzling breaks that mold slightly, but the very design and vision of the site are such that it attempts to limit the social interaction to a minimum.
If you peruse the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and help center, you'll notice things about "ask questions, get answers, no distractions", and help center articles about the proper way to use comments (as little as possible). Stack Exchange was designed to be a non-social site, and so having "friends" and "follows" is *very* highly unlikely.

You are welcome to step into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair), though, which is the most social part of the network. While it's not the most active, it gives you an opportunity to interact with other members of the community in a less formal environment. We also play word games and such ;)

---

Since you mentioned watching out for new content by another person, note that Stack Exchange does give you an option to set up a feed for when a user posts. If you go to a user's profile, head to the "activity" tab, and scroll all the way to the bottom, you'll see a "user feed" button on the left, under the "accounts" thing. This will lead you to an [RSS feed](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/25966), that you can then use in whatever feed tracking thing you use (such as Feedly).